InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid Metrics format
I was trying to add evolution to a existing model in GCP but I am getting this error:

InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid Metrics format.

from google.cloud.aiplatform import gapic
from google.cloud import aiplatform

# Simplified metrics dictionary to test the schema's requirements
metrics = {
    "classificationMetrics": {
        "auPrc": 0.88,
        "logLoss": 0.66
    }
}

# Initialize the ModelEvaluation object with minimal fields
model_eval = gapic.ModelEvaluation(
    display_name="eval",
    metrics_schema_uri="gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/modelevaluation/classification_metrics_1.0.0.yaml",
    metrics=metrics
)

# Set up the API endpoint and client
API_ENDPOINT = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
client = gapic.ModelServiceClient(client_options={"api_endpoint": API_ENDPOINT})

# Import the model evaluation
client.import_model_evaluation(parent=model.resource_name, model_evaluation=model_eval)

This is my code but I am not able to correct this please help
I tried to change the metrics format but still I have the same problem
